# how to get server machine date in winform?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am using winform, mysql, c# in my project.

I want to get server machine, which was connected throw LAN network. Is it possible in winform or C#?.

My Requirement was,..

Product License date was stored in mysql database. I can get that and compare to local system date. but client change the local system date at anytime. So License date  process is waste, when i am comaper that with local machine. But the Client didnot change the server date.

So i am willing to get the Server Date.

Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [MySQL Now()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function:

> Returns the current date and time as a
>   value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or
>   YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format,
>   depending on whether the function is
>   used in a string or numeric context.
>   The value is expressed in the current
>   time zone.

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL is on your server, then use this to get the date.  In fact, you can use this to perform the check and return you a result.

Answer (score 1):

Use MYSQL's [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) function - that way you'll always have the UTC time instead of whatever the server's own local time is currently.